# Moving index of array by a number

Tags: arrays, swift

So lets say I have this array:

```
var array = ["a","b","c","d"]
```

Is it possible to move the whole index 2 spaces to the right for example? It should look like this:

```
var array = ["c","d","a","b"]
```

What function can I call for this to happen?

Comment: Various solutions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31554670/shift-swift-array and here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33264959/swift-shift-elements-in-array-by-index.

Comment: var array = ["a","b","c","d"]                                  

func shiftArray(array:[String],byIndex:Int) -> [String]{
    let newArray = Array(array.suffixFrom(byIndex))
    let newArray2 = Array(array.prefixUpTo(byIndex))
    return newArray + newArray2
}

shiftArray(array, byIndex: 2)