# Negative number modulo in swift

Tags: ios, swift

How does modulo of negative numbers work in swift ?
When i did (-1 % 3) it is giving -1 but the remainder is 2. What is the catch in it?

Comment: Swift is correct. -1 / 3 = 0 with a remainder of -1.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The Swift *remainder operator* `%` computes the remainder of 
the integer division:

```
a % b = a - (a/b) * b
```

where `/` is the truncating integer division. In your case

```
(-1) % 3 = (-1) - ((-1)/3) * 3 = (-1) - 0 * 3 = -1
```

So the remainder has always the same sign as the *dividend* (unless
the remainder is zero).

This is the same definition as required e.g. in the C99 standard,
see for example
[Does either ANSI C or ISO C specify what -5 % 10 should be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3609572/does-either-ansi-c-or-iso-c-specify-what-5-10-should-be). See also
 [Wikipedia: Modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) for an overview
how this is handled in different programming languages.

A "true" modulus function could be defined in Swift like this:

```
func mod(_ a: Int, _ n: Int) -> Int {
    precondition(n > 0, "modulus must be positive")
    let r = a % n
    return r >= 0 ? r : r + n
}

print(mod(-1, 3)) // 2
```

Answer (score 6):

From the [Language Guide - Basic Operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html):

> #### Remainder Operator
>
> The remainder operator (`a % b`) works out how many multiples of `b`
>   will fit inside `a` and returns the value that is left over (known as
>   the remainder).
>
> The remainder operator (`%`) is also known as a modulo operator in
>   other languages. However, **its behavior in Swift for negative numbers
>   means that it is, strictly speaking, a remainder rather than a modulo
>   operation**.
>
> ...
>
> The same method is applied when calculating the remainder for a
>   negative value of a:
>
> ```
> -9 % 4   // equals -1
> ```
>
> Inserting `-9` and `4` into the equation yields:
>
> ```
> -9 = (4 x -2) + -1
> ```
>
> giving a remainder value of `-1`.

In your case, no `3` will fit in `1`, and the remainder is `1` (same with `-1` -> remainder is `-1`).

Comment: The documentation can certainly be improved. *"The largest multiple of `4` that fits into `-9`"* is not very clear...

Comment: @MartinR agreed :)

Answer (score 4):

If what you are really after is capturing a number between 0 and b, try using this:

```
infix operator %%

extension Int {
    static  func %% (_ left: Int, _ right: Int) -> Int {
        if left >= 0 { return left % right }
        if left >= -right { return (left+right) }
        return ((left % right)+right)%right
    }
}

print(-1 %% 3) //prints 2
```

This will work for all value of a, unlike the the previous answer while will only work if a > -b.

I prefer the %% operator over just overloading %, as it will be very clear that you are not doing a true mod function.

The reason for the if statements, instead of just using the final return line, is for speed, as a mod function requires a division, and divisions are more costly that a conditional.

Answer (score 1):

An answer inspired by cdeerinck, which sacrifices speed for simplicity, is this:

```
infix operator %%

extension Int {

    static  func %% (_ left: Int, _ right: Int) -> Int {
       let mod = left % right
       return mod >= 0 ? mod : mod + right
    }

}
```

I tested it with this little loop in a playground:

```
for test in [6, 5, 4, 0, -1, -2, -100, -101] {
    print(test, "%% 5", test %% 5)
}
```

Comment: There is discussion of it here, with alternative solutions: https://forums.swift.org/t/modulo-operation-in-swift/7018 . Martin R's answer is the same algorithm as mine, but he uses generics to make it more useful.

Comment: I don't think this is sacrificing speed— @cdeerinck's has 2 branches, whereas yours has 1.

Answer (score 0):

Martin has [a great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41180619/2547229) clarifying that Swifts **`%` is a remainder** operator rather than a modulo operator and provides a modulo implementation to handle the case of a negative remainder.

Swift also has a very useful function `quotientAndRemainder` on `BinaryInteger`:

```swift
func quotientAndRemainder(dividingBy rhs: Self) -> (quotient: Self, remainder: Self)
```

I've found it helpful to write a similar "modulo" dual for this with special handling for a negative remainder…

```swift
extension BinaryInteger {
    public func quotientAndModulo(dividingBy divider: Self) -> (quotient: Self, modulo: Self) {
        let (q, r) = quotientAndRemainder(dividingBy: divider)
        return r >= 0 ? (q, r) : (q - 1, divider + r)
    }
}
```