# truncatingRemainder vs remainder in Swift

Tags: swift

Swift's substitutes for the % symbol for floating point numbers:

---

```
func truncatingRemainder(dividingBy other: Self) -> Self
```

> Returns the remainder of this value divided by the given value using
>   truncating division.

---

```
func remainder(dividingBy other: Self) -> Self
```

> Returns the remainder of this value divided by the given value.

---

The documentation didn't seem terribly clear. What's the practical difference between them, and when should each be used in preference to the other? Thanks.

Comment: Additional note in case anyone is thrown by this: the remainder operators such as % and truncatingRemainder aren't the same as modulo, they're different for negatives. See here for a true mod function in swift: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41180619/297981

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[`truncatingRemainder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/2885641-truncatingremainder) computes the remainder of the "truncating
division", and [`remainder`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/2884269-remainder) computes the remainder of the "rounding division".

Example (from the API reference):

```
let x = 8.625
let y = 0.75
```

Truncating division and remainder:

```
let q1 = (x/y).rounded(.towardZero)
let r1 = x.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: y)

print(q1, r1)      // 11.0 0.375
print(q1 * y + r1) // 8.625
```

Rounding division and remainder:

```
let q2 = (x/y).rounded(.toNearestOrEven)
let r2 = x.remainder(dividingBy: y)

print(q2, r2)      // 12.0 -0.375
print(q2 * y + r2) // 8.625
```

So in any case, the remainder `rem` of a division `x` by `y` is

```
rem = x - quot * y
```

where `quot` is "a rounded quotient" of the division `x` by `y`.

For `truncatingRemainder`, `quot` is the quotient
rounded towards zero, and for `remainder`, `quot` is the quotient
rounded towards the nearest integer.

The result of `truncatingRemainder` has always the same *sign*
as the dividend, this need not be the case for `remainder`.

If both `x` and `y` are *exactly* representable as an integer
then the result of

```
x.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: y)
```

is the same as

```
Int(x) % Int(y)
```

with the integer remainder operator `%`.

Answer (score 6):

This looks like a job for...playgrounds!

```
let thing: Float = 8126.84652
let truncating = thing.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 10) // value is 6.84668, analog to %
let nonTruncating = thing.remainder(dividingBy: 10) // -3.15332
```

As you can see, the plain remainder is allowed to go negative, (or rather, subtracts until the value is <=0) whereas the truncating remainder will remain positive. (stops when the value is >=0)

Comment: truncatingRemainder doesn't always return a positive value. The return value is the same sign as 'thing'