# Swift Double.remainder(dividingBy:) returning negative value

Tags: swift, modulus, negative-number

```
let num = 32.0
Double(num).remainder(dividingBy: 12.0)
```

I'm getting -4?..instead of 8.0...it's subtracting 12.0 from 8.0

how do i fix this?

Comment: Unrelated but  `Double(...` is redundant. Swift infers a floating point literal as `Double` by default.

Comment: If we want to know the remainder of 32 divided by 12, why aren't we using Ints and `%` here? Unless you have a very good reason to use Double (a reason that is not at all evident from the example), don't.

Comment: Related: [truncatingRemainder vs remainder in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42724234/1187415)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Please, read the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/2884269-remainder) carefully:

> For two finite values x and y, the remainder r of dividing x by y satisfies x == y * q + r, where q is the integer **nearest** to x / y. If x / y is exactly halfway between two integers, q is chosen to be even. Note that q is not x / y computed in floating-point arithmetic, and that q may not be representable in any available integer type.

(emphasis mine)

You want to use [truncatingRemainder(dividingBy:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/2885641-truncatingremainder) instead:

```
let num = 32.0
let value = Double(num)
    .truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: 12)
print(value) // 8
```

Comment: Interesting sidenote, if you write `Double(num) % 12`, there is an error in Xcode saying that `%` is not available and you should use `truncatingRemainder` instead.

Comment: @matt I meant that Xcode will actually tell you what method to use.

Comment: Ah, I see. Okay, but we don't know what the OP's intentions are. So far it's just weird that we're not converting to Int in the first place... :)

Comment: From the docs, it says "...where q is the **integer** nearest to x / y." And then it says "q may not be representable in any integer type."  That leaves me confused.

Comment: @DuncanC Double can be bigger than any possible integer.

Answer (score 2):

`remainder(dividingBy:)`is not the modulus function.

In real division `32.0/12.0 = 2.666666...`. The [remainder(dividingBy:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/double/2884269-remainder) function defines the nearest integer to that result as `q`: in this case `3`. So we write:

```
32.O = q * 12 + r
```

With `q` being an integer, and `r` a Double.

```
32.0 = 3 * 12.0 + r ⇒ r = - 4.0
```

The remainder `r`, as defined by this function, is `-4.0`.