# Cleanest way to wrap array index?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

Say I have an array of 5 Ints. What would be the most efficient way to wrap the index of the array if the index were incremented or decremented (for example) the following occurs?

where n = 0: `arr[n-1]` // -> `arr[4]` (wraps from 0 back to the end of the array)

where n = 2: `arr[n+1]` // -> `arr[3]` (behaves as normal)

where n = 4: `arr[n+1]` // -> `arr[0]` (wraps to 0 from the end of the array)

Comment: use the `%` `mod` operation

Comment: Could you clarify? Because I don't see how that works when decrementing from 0.

Comment: When decrementing you just use an `if` statement or a ternary operator to check for index < 0 and set the index to `count - 1`

Comment: @ColGraff below solved the problem allowing me to avoid any `if`s elegantly.

Comment: [Related SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41180292/negative-number-modulo-in-swift) (although not a duplicate target).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the mod operation which will get you to a range of -count to count, then add count back in and mod again:

```
let foo = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

for i in -6...7 {
  print(i, foo[(i % foo.count + foo.count) % foo.count])
}

//  -6 0
//  -5 1
//  -4 2
//  -3 3
//  -2 4
//  -1 5
//  0 0
//  1 1
//  2 2
//  3 3
//  4 4
//  5 5
//  6 0
```

This works for both directions.

Comment: This is the magic I was looking for: `foo[(n % foo.count + foo.count) % foo.count]` where `n+1` and `n-1` both wrap properly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

A bit late to the party, but if you're facing the same issue and have a lot of use cases for wrap-around array indices, you could also put the `%`-solution from the accepted answer in a simple subscript extension of Array, like so:

```
extension Array {
    subscript (wrapping index: Int) -> Element {
        return self[(index % self.count + self.count) % self.count]
    }
}
```

Example Usage:

```
let array = ["a","b","c"]
print( array[wrapping: 0] )   // a
print( array[wrapping: 4] )   // b
print( array[wrapping: -1] )  // c
```

Answer (score 0):

Cleanest I can do for only positive integers is this

```swift
extension Array{
    subscript(wrapAround index: Int) -> Element {
        return self[index % self.count]
    }
}
```