# How to wrap around the index when reaching the end or beginning of an array in c#?

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

Im currently writing a weapon script for a FPS and I want to switch weapons with the mouse wheel. I created an array with the weapons in it and everytime I scroll up with the mouse wheel the index of the weapon increases by one. My problem is that when I'm at the last weapon I get IndexOutOfBounds error message. I've tried to reset the weapon index to 0 if its at the end of the array but for some reason that didn't work. I've also tried to do it with a while loop instead of an if-statement but that didn't work as well. Here's the code:

```
public class WeaponManager : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField]
    private WeaponHandler[] weapons;

    private int current_weapon_index;

    void Start()
    {
        current_weapon_index = 0;
        weapons[current_weapon_index].gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }

    
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha1))
        {
            TurnOnSelectedWeapon(0);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha2))
        {
            TurnOnSelectedWeapon(1);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha3))
        {
            TurnOnSelectedWeapon(2);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha4))
        {
            TurnOnSelectedWeapon(3);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha5))
        {
            TurnOnSelectedWeapon(4);
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Alpha6))
        {
            TurnOnSelectedWeapon(5);
        }

        if(Input.mouseScrollDelta.y > 0)
        {
            SwitchToNextWeapon();
        }

        if (Input.mouseScrollDelta.y < 0)
        {
            SwitchToPreviousWeapon();
        }
    }

    void TurnOnSelectedWeapon(int weaponIndex)
    {
        weapons[current_weapon_index].gameObject.SetActive(false);

        weapons[weaponIndex].gameObject.SetActive(true);

        current_weapon_index = weaponIndex;
    }

    void SwitchToNextWeapon()
    {
        weapons[current_weapon_index].gameObject.SetActive(false);

        current_weapon_index++;
       
        weapons[current_weapon_index].gameObject.SetActive(true);

        if (current_weapon_index >= weapons.Length)
        {
            current_weapon_index = 0;
        }
    }

    void SwitchToPreviousWeapon()
    {
        weapons[current_weapon_index].gameObject.SetActive(false);

        current_weapon_index--;

        weapons[current_weapon_index].gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: `current_weapon_index = current_weapon_index % weapons.Length` - something like this.

Comment: @GuruStron which works fine for incrementing but what happens when you decrement below 0?

Answer (score 1):

It would be quite straightforward to implement a class which handles this for you, just maintaining an internal `List<>` of items. Add a `Current` property to read the currently selected item, as well as a `MoveNext`/`MovePrevious` methods to be called from your mouse wheel handler

```
public class ContinuousList<T>
{
    private List<T> internalList = new List<T>();
    private int currentIndex = 0;

    public void Add(T item) => internalList.Add(item);

    public T Current { get => internalList[currentIndex]; }

    public void MoveNext()
    {
       currentIndex++;
       if(currentIndex >= internalList.Count) currentIndex = 0;
    }

    public void MovePrevious()
    {
       currentIndex--;
       if(currentIndex <= 0) currentIndex = internalList.Count - 1;
    }
}
```

Usage assuming you maybe have some weapons which have a base class `Weapon`:

```
var weaponList = new ContinuousList<Weapon>();
weaponList.Add(new Sword()); 
weaponList.Add(new Axe());
var currentWeapon = weaponList.Current; // gets Sword
weaponList.MoveNext();
var currentWeapon = weaponList.Current; // gets Axe
weaponList.MoveNext();
var currentWeapon = weaponList.Current; // Back to Sword
```

Live example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ji7rkt

Note that it is very easy to implement `IEnumerable<T>` on this `ContinuousList` so that it can be used in any enumerations and with LINQ methods. I did not want to complicate a simple example with this but to see this in action check here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/NtdfDi

Comment: As a small improvement, you can look at implementing `IEnumerable<T>` or `IEnumerator<T>`, which makes the class functional with `foreach` construct and a few other places just like a normal list.

Comment: @Alejandro indeed. I held off doing so as to not compicate the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
void SwitchToNextWeapon()
{
    weapons[current_weapon_index].gameObject.SetActive(false);
    var temp = current_weapon_index + 1;
    current_weapon_index = temp >= weapons.Count() ? 0 : temp;
    
    weapons[current_weapon_index].gameObject.SetActive(true);
}

void SwitchToPreviousWeapon()
{
    weapons[current_weapon_index].gameObject.SetActive(false);
    var temp = current_weapon_index - 1;
    current_weapon_index = temp < 0 ? weapons.Count() - 1 : temp;

    weapons[current_weapon_index].gameObject.SetActive(true);
}
```

Just add a check before increasing or decreasing current weapon index. If it reaches max, then revert to 0 and if it's reached min (`0`) then set index to max.

Comment: Since `weapons` is an array I would say it is better to use `Length`.

Comment: It worked! Thanks! Could you maybe explain why it didn't work the way I did it? I just want to know so that I can avoid similar mistakes. You don't have to, of course.

Comment: @L1NTHALO Glad that it helped! In your code you were trying to access the item using new increased and decreased index before checking for it's validity.

Answer (score 1):

Cyclic values are easily handled using a modulo (`%`) operator.

```
int mod = 5;

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i % mod);
}
```

You'll see that the output cycles from 0 to `mod-1`: 0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,...

This covers the case for incrementing by one:

```
int index = 4;
int mod = myArray.Length; // assume 5 items in the array

// Increment and cycle
index = ++index % mod;
```

You'll see that index is now `0` because you were at the end of the list, so the next item should be at the start of the list.

---

However, there is a bit of an issue for decrementing cyclical values. For a reason I don't understand, C# has opted to allow for negative modulo values, i.e.:

```
-1 % 5 = -1
```

... instead of `4`, which is what you'd expect.
*Edit: It is contended in the comments that `4` is not what everyone would expect. From experience when I was tackling this issue for the first time, I found a lot of confusion/annoyance online at the existence of negative modulo results, but I cannot disprove that this is observation bias on my part.*

I've tackled this issue in the past, and the easiest way to solve this is to:

- Take the modulo
- Add the modulo
- Take the modulo again

In essence, **if** the first step ends up with a negative result (e.g. `-1`), we simply add the modulo, therefore pushing the value above zero. However, if the first step was already a positive result, we've now made the value too high. Therefore, by taking the modulo again, we are able to cancel out the potentially too high value. This covers both cases.

[Here is a dotnetfiddle to prove that it works](https://dotnetfiddle.net/FY7PUb).

In other words:

```
public int Increment(int current, int mod)
{
    return ((++current % mod) + mod) % mod;
}

public int Decrement(int current, int mod)
{
    return ((--current % mod) + mod) % mod;
}
```

For the sake of DRY, you can reshape it so you only use this complex formula once

```
public int Cycle(int current, int mod)
{
    return ((current % mod) + mod) % mod;
}
```

... but then you have to manually in/decrement the value first. Which version you prefer is up to you.

Comment: "which is what you'd expect" - it might be what *you* expect, but it is already functioning in the way that I would expect; expectations may be a little subjective.

Comment: @MarcGravell: I would expect that most people expect that `% x` outputs an integer value between `0` and `x-1`, not between `-x+1` and `x-1`. My expectation is based on the sheer amount of confusion and annoyance I found online when I was tackling this negative modulo issue the first time. However, maybe if you start from a specific use case where negative results make sense, it could be different and more intuitive. I can't attest to that since I started from using them for simple cyclical values.

Comment: Isn't this basically what I also did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68999275/7111561)?

Comment: @derHugo: In terms of the specific way to account for negative moduli, yes that is the same formula. But an answer is more than just its code snippet, and I wanted to provide a more in-depth explanation regarding the underlying math.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45397603/cleanest-way-to-wrap-array-index) is for swift but basically applies in the same way in `c#`.

So in general you can wrap any given index to an array length by applying modulo twice.

This works in more general cases, not only for moving a single step up and down:

```
public static class ArrayUtils
{
    public static void Forward<T>(ref int currentIndex, T[] array, int amount)
    {
        currentIndex = WrapIndex(currentIndex + amount, array);
    }
    
    public static void Backward<T>(ref int currentIndex, T[] array, int amount)
    {
        currentIndex = WrapIndex(currentIndex - amount, array);
    }
    
    public static int WrapIndex<T>(int newIndex, T[] array)
    {
        var length = array.Length;
        return ((newIndex % length) + length) % length;
    }
}
```

See [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/M7wFbb)

Which you can now use for any array.