# Swift: Get next highest number that ends in zero

Tags: swift, algorithm

I have to run some algorithms on certain health industry numbers for validations. One of them requires checking if a total at a certain point ends in zero, if not get the next highest number that ends in zero. I have this code but am wondering if there is a better way to do it:

```
let strTotal = String(iTotal)
    var iSubtractor = iTotal

    if Int(String(strTotal.last!))! != 0 {
        var bIsZeroEnding = false

        repeat {

            iSubtractor += 1
            let strSubstractor = String(iSubtractor)
            if Int(String(strSubstractor.last!))! == 0 {
                bIsZeroEnding = true
            }

        } while !bIsZeroEnding
    }
```

Doh...I do see the typo in my var name...strSubstractor... :D

Comment: what exactly is iTotal? an int?

Comment: What about `let newNumber = ((oldNumber + 9)/10) * 10`, without all that string stuff ?

Comment: what about `var value = 75` and then `repeat { value+=1 } while !(value%10) == 0))`

Comment: i am a bit confused by the expression  "next highest number": do you want the next, or the highest number of the remaining ones? let your list be 11, 20, 30. You've parsed 11; 20 is the next number, 30 is the highest. Is your list maybe sorted? I think it would be beneficial if you could edit your post including an example of your input list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I have this code but am wondering if there is a better way to do it

Yes, there is. Rounding up a (non-negative) integer to the next multiple of 10 can be far more simply done with

```
let roundedNumber = ((oldNumber + 9)/10) * 10
```

without the need for any conversion to strings. We add 9 and then
round down to the next multiple of 10 (using the fact that
integer division *truncates* the result to an integer result).

Comment: Can you explain this one to me? `((5+9)/10) * 10` becomes 14? (5+9)

Comment: @Vollan: The integer division *truncates,* so `((5+9)/10) * 10`  becomes `(14/10) * 10 = 1 * 10 = 10`

Comment: Ah right, forgot about the int truncating, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This is all you need to do:

```
var desiredNumber = ceil(Double(iTotal)/10)*10
```

How this method works:

- Let's assume our original number is 37. If we divide it by 10, we get 3.7.
- If we ceil 3.7, we get 4. Multiplying it by the divider will get us 40. This works with every divider.

Comment: Alternatively use the `rounded(.up)`  method from `Double`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ceil`. It works with both (non-negative) and (negative) numbers.

```
extension CGFloat {
    func nearest(to num: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        return num * ceil(self/num)
    }
}

let value: CGFloat = 53.0
print(value.nearest(to: 10))
```

**output: 60.0**

Alternatively for pure `int` you can get it with the help of `remainder` operator `(%)`.

```
let value: Int = 33
let rem: Int = value%10

// Here, If rem == 0 that means number is fully divisible by 10 (Contains 0 at last)
let result: Int = (rem == 0) ? value : value + (10 - rem)
```

Comment: Nitpicking: `%` computes a *remainder,* not the modulus :)

Comment: Oh, I was actually specifying the `operator name`.

Comment: `%` is the *remainder operator*

Comment: Isn't % [modulus operator](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=modulus+operator&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=izPQWovrKILm8wf71ZyoBg)?

Comment: I guess for positive integers there is not difference in both.

Comment: That is correct (compare e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41180292/negative-number-modulo-in-swift)