# Understanding Remainder operator

Tags: operators, modulo

Just doing some basic modulo operations and trying to wrap my head around the below operations with questions marks.

```
0%5 // 0 - Totally understand
1%5 // 1 ?
2%5 // 2 ?
3%5 // 3 ?
4%5 // 4 ?
5%5 // 0 - Totally understand
```

Perhaps I'm thinking in the wrong way. For example 1/5 would return a `Double` of 0.2 and not a single `integer` so how does it return a remainder of `1`?

I understand these. It makes sense but the above I can't wrap my head around.

```
9%4   // 1
10%2  // 0
10%6  // 4
```

Be great if someone could explain this. Seems I'm having a brain fart. [Source of learning](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html).

Comment: What's wrong with module. `1 = 5 * 0 + 1`. Actually 1/5 will return 0, not 0.2. Because of 1 and 5 is `Int` type

Comment: Note that `%` is the *remainder operator,* not *modulo.* Compare [Negative number modulo in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41180292/1187415).

Comment: 1%5 can fit no complete 5's, so the remainder is one. Hence 2 % 5 can fit no complete 5's and the remainder is 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the same [Basic Operators](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/BasicOperators.html) page that you link to:

> The remainder operator (`a % b`) works out how many multiples of `b` will fit inside `a` and returns the value that is left over (known as the remainder).

### Specifically for `1 % 5`:

`5` doesn't fit in `1`, so it fits `0` times.

This means that `1` can be described as

```
1 = (5 * multiplier) + remainder
```

Since the multiplier is `0`, the `remainder` is `1`

```
1 = (5 * 0) + remainder
1 = remainder
```

If we instead look at `6 % 5` the remainder is also `1`. This is because `5` fit in `6` one time:

```
6 = (5 * multiplier) + remainder
6 = (5 * 1) + remainder
6-5 = remainder
1 = remainder
```

Answer (score 0):

This **/** the division operator when you say `1/5` if division is in integer it'll give `0` , but this `1.0/0.5` when you make it in Double , it'll give `0.2`

but **%** the modulo operator when you say `1%5 = 1` because you have `1 = 0*5 + 1` which means that 1 has zero number of `5` and the reminder is `1`

Comment: `%` in Swift is NOT the modulo operator.

Comment: I think modulo and remainder are used interchangeably

Comment: Remainder and modulo behave differently for negative numbers. Swift's behavior for negative numbers makes it, strictly speaking, a remainder operator.